# How to remove web.config file in iis

Tags: powershell, iis

I have an IIS web page created by this command

```
New-Website -Force -Name TestSite -Port 8080 -HostHeader TestSite -PhysicalPath C:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

And i want to be able to pass the command into script and clear ALL configs in iis and than create new web-site.

I've tried some commands from Microsoft site. Like `Clear-IISConfigCollection`

But i'm not fully sure of how it works.

So i'm asking for help of how to CLEAR configs before creating new web page.

Thanks.

Comment: PowerShell gives you both access to IIS settings and file system, so **it is your responsibility** to use that access and write the right script.

Comment: @LexLi And i'm here, because i don't know hot to do this? Because i've tried something first of all?

Comment: I wonder what you meant by "CLEAR configs". You said "to remove" the web.config file, which is not equivalent to "clear configs". Again, make a clear question with enough details, or you won't get what you wanted.

Comment: @LexLi Check edit please

Comment: Clear-IISConfigCollection is not what you wanted, as it only applies to individual collections and in fact just generates `<clear>` tags as the documentation says. For you, the most likely option is to restore from a backup https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/restore-webconfiguration?view=winserver2012-ps

Comment: I also couldn't understand your requirement about clear the web.config. Do you mean you want to delete the whole web.config file or set the web.config as a default setting?

Comment: @BrandoZhang I haven't found how, but i need to reset all configs to default

Comment: @BrandoZhang And than create new web-page and fill it again so it can work from the box.

Comment: As far as I know, a web application may contains two kinds of setting one is set in the web.config file another settings are set in the applicationhost.config file. Do you mean you want to reset all the setting to the default not only the web.config?